# How to list client details in a table vertically Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to display some client details when the user clicks a specific point on a map. How do I achieve the below ?

The details should be in the following format:

```
Individual
 ID: 01
 Name: Kenny
 Phone Number: 1512
Business
 BID: 02
 Name: Starbucks
 Phone Number: 123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can show these details using a tooltip. The Tooltip has option to display the data from dimensions. Additionally you have the flexibility to format and arrange the data in the order that you have given.

Comment: If the value is blank, I won't be able to hide it in the tooltip ?

Comment: That is correct. You cannot hide the labels associated with the value. However you may use calculated fields in the values and display any custom message.